# FluentValidation chained validators in rule receive cached instance and/or property value?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I need some clarification on how exactly the instance whos property is being validated, is passed down to each validator in a rule.

Let's assume the following:

`RuleFor(x => x.MyProperty).SetValidator(new MyCustomValidator()).NotNull();`

The **MyCustomValidator** will set a value on **MyProperty** if the value is NULL in **some cases**.
I would expect that the **NotNull** validation would pass.

However, it appears this is not the case.

When I split up the RuleFor into two seperate calls:

```
RuleFor(x => x.MyProperty).SetValidator(new MyCustomValidator());
RuleFor(x => x.MyProperty).NotNull();
```

it works as expected.
But of course, i'd like to avoid having multiple "RuleFor" statements for the same property

This makes me believe that at the start of the "RuleFor", the instance and/or property value being validated is cached/copied and then provided to each validator specified for that rule.

I've also created a fiddle demonstrating this behaviour here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rDTrDU

Comment: I would say that modifiyng data in a validator in general is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chained one will create one `PropertyRule` with multiple components and when they are processed `FluentValidation` [caches property value](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/f818399331dd38f4fcf50a62f5012799308cb651/src/FluentValidation/Internal/PropertyRule.cs#L108) and uses it [for every component](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/f818399331dd38f4fcf50a62f5012799308cb651/src/FluentValidation/Internal/PropertyRule.cs#L113):

```cs
var accessor = new Lazy<TProperty>(() => PropertyFunc(context.InstanceToValidate), LazyThreadSafetyMode.None);
```

The not chained one creates multiple `PropertyRule`s with one component so after the first rule is validated the `MyObject` instance will be modified and property accessor will use the new value.

In your case I would try to use `PreValidate` in `MyObjectValidator`:

```
public class MyObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<MyObject>
{
    protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<MyObject> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        var version = context.RootContextData["SourceVersion"] as Version;
        if (version < new Version(2, 0, 0) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.InstanceToValidate.MyProperty))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t[DEBUG]: Setting value to 'Hello world'");
            context.InstanceToValidate.MyProperty = "Hello world";
        }
        return true;
    }
  ....
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the same thing after I copied the source for the NotNullValidator into the fiddle and hooking it up.
context.InstanceToValidate does have its property value updated, but the second parameter of the IsValid method still has the old value.

Bummer but oh well, at least now I know for sure :)

Comment: @DirkS. see the update. It seems you can override `PreValidate` in  `MyObjectValidator` to achieve the desired behaviour in the chained case.

Comment: Ah cheers!

I'll play around with it, see if I can make it fit that way. nice catch!